# Ampersand (&) character is being ignored in Oracle ORDER BY

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by, ampersand

I am running a query in Oracle and that query is ordered by a column that may have values with ampersand. However, it seems that ampersand is being ignored by the sorting algorithm.

For instance:

```
select * from (
    select '&' txt from dual
    union
    select 'P' txt from dual
    union
    select 'N' txt from dual
)
order by txt
```

Prints exactly (and correctly, I guess):

```
&
N
P
```

However, if I change the text with '&' to '&Z', the result changes:

```
select * from (
    select '&'||'Z' txt from dual // concatenating just to
                                  // avoid variable substitution
    union
    select 'P' txt from dual
    union
    select 'N' txt from dual
)
order by txt
```

Result is then:

```
N
P
&Z
```

If I change 'Z' to 'A' then the result is:

```
&A
N
P
```

It seems that the '&' is not being considered by ORDER BY clause. Does anyone know if this is expected behavior or if I am missing some configuration step? I understand that one needs to escape ampersand for inserts or updates. But thing is that the character is already in the table!

Thanks in advance, guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the effect of linguistic sorting:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_sort=binary;

Session altered.

SQL> get afiedt.buf
  1  select * from (
  2  select '&' txt from dual
  3  union
  4  select '&'||'Z' txt from dual
  5  union
  6  select '&'||'A' txt from dual
  7  union
  8  select 'P' txt from dual
  9  union
 10  select 'N' txt from dual
 11  )
 12* order by txt
SQL> /

TX
--
&
&A
&Z
N
P

SQL> alter session set nls_sort = 'Dutch';

Session altered.

SQL> get afiedt.buf
  1  select * from (
  2  select '&' txt from dual
  3  union
  4  select '&'||'Z' txt from dual
  5  union
  6  select '&'||'A' txt from dual
  7  union
  8  select 'P' txt from dual
  9  union
 10  select 'N' txt from dual
 11  )
 12* order by txt
SQL> /

TX
--
&
&A
N
P
&Z
```

It does make a difference for what language you are sorting. Some characters have different values depending on their language. With binary you sort using the ascii values.

Comment: Linguistic sorting has [ignorable characters](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm#i1006286) but no idea if that can include `&` as punctuation.

Comment: Nice reading about the ampersand <http://glossographia.wordpress.com/2009/01/13/a-biography-of-the-ampersand/> Not that it makes anything much clearer but it is a complex thing.

Comment: Also see <http://www.websters-online-dictionary.org/definitions/ampersand?cx=partner-pub-0939450753529744%3Av0qd01-tdlq&cof=FORID%3A9&ie=UTF-8&q=ampersand&sa=Search#922> where it is listed as a punctuation mark.

Comment: Thanks @ik_zelf, it worked like you said. @alex-poole I'll take a look at the ignorable characters page you posted.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on your NLS_LANGUAGE and NLS_SORT setting.

I get the following on Oracle 10g, with NLS_LANGUAGE = `AMERICAN` and NLS_SORT = (null).

```
TXT 
--- 
&   
N   
P   

TXT 
--- 
&Z  
N   
P
```