# handling ampersand(&) in an sql statement

Tags: javascript, sql, regex, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I ignore ampersands in a SQL script running from SQL Plus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118190/how-do-i-ignore-ampersands-in-a-sql-script-running-from-sql-plus)

I have an using an sql statement where there is an ampersand(&) explicitly used in the WHERE clause.

**e.g. select * from table1 where column1 IN('abc',"'a & b',''def')**

In this statement I am getting the values for the IN clause as a comma separated string **e.g.string1="'abc',"'a & b',''def'"**

which I directly use it to build my sql query.
Now when I try to run this query I am unable to execute this query as when I execute it during run time it is asking for a replacement character for ampersand .

how do I change or alter my query so that I can get to use the ampersand

Should I use a regex on the string which I get to manipulate to make it work.As the string(comma seperated value) I am using in the sql query is coming from a text box.
the database I am using is Oracle

please help

Comment: Have you tried using a parameterized query?

Answer (score 2):

[This Oracle Technology Network forum discussion](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=466604) offers various workarounds for this problem. The simplest, in my opinion, is one of the first suggestions, which is to replace this:

```
'a & b'
```

with this:

```
'a &' || ' b'
```

but you can look through that page to see if any of the other ideas sounds better to you.

(Though I have to say — I'm a bit worried that you're getting this error. It makes it sound almost as though you were just plugging the user-submitted text right into SQL*Plus . . . which, if it were the case, would be *really* bad. What would happen if the user submitted `'; \n DROP TABLE users;`?)

Answer (score 0):

if `'a&b'` is a Column name, you can use like below.

```
'A&B'
```

it will solve the recognizing ampersand problem.
and as @ruakh told using `||`, that trick will do work.
These [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682949/ampersand-character-is-being-ignored-in-oracle-order-by) and [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118190/how-do-i-ignore-ampersands-in-a-sql-script-running-from-sql-plus) will help You.
for more information check this [forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2229657)